# how to insert 'and'(in place of comma) in between elements of a list, when using piecewise MAPLE 2018

Tags: maple

I have a list of inequalities represent a certain expression, Now I want to use these list elements in a piece wise function.

```
list1 :=[a < 0, c < 0, -2*k*a < b];
list2 :=[0 < c, a < 0, b < -2*k*a];
list3 :=[0 < a, b < -2*k*a, c < 0];
```

for each list there is a respective expression to be displayed, my idea is to use piecewise function to show as below

```
piecewise(a < 0 and c < 0 and -2*k*a < b, expr1, 0 < c and a < 0 and b < -2*k*a, expr2, 0 < a and b < -2*k*a and c < 0, expr3)
```

expr1,expr2,expr3 are respective expressions.

how could I possibly achieve this??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
restart;

list1 :=[a < 0, c < 0, -2*k*a < b]:
list2 :=[0 < c, a < 0, b < -2*k*a]:
list3 :=[0 < a, b < -2*k*a, c < 0]:
```

You can use the so-called prefix form (operator form) for `and`, but note that this requires putting single left-quotes around that (since it's a language key-word).

```
`and`(op(list1));

             a < 0 and c < 0 and -2 k a < b
```

And so the `piecewise` can be constructed similarly,

```
allconds := [list1, list2, list3]:
allexpr := [expr1, expr2, expr3]:

piecewise( seq( op( [ `and`(op(allconds[i])),
                      allexpr[i] ] ),
                i = 1 .. nops(allconds) ) );

       / expr1      a < 0 and c < 0 and -2 k a < b
       |                                          
      <  expr2      0 < c and a < 0 and b < -2 k a
       |                                          
       \ expr3      0 < a and b < -2 k a and c < 0
```

Answer (score 1):

@ acer Thank you for the solution,

I have also working on other method since yesterday which is bit complex(bit similar to your method) to understand and as compact and simple as yours.

Since, the number of lists(list1,list2....) can change based on expressions. I have combines these lists in to subset of one big list bigList. Terms is list of Expressions

```
biglist :=[list1,list2,list3];
Terms :=[Expr1,Expr2,Expr3]


conditions := seq([apply(`and`, op(bigList[i]))], i = 1 .. nops(bigList)); 
sequence := seq([conditions[i][1], Terms[i]], i = 1 .. nops([conditions])); 

pieceWiseResult := piecewise(seq(op(sequence[i]), i = 1 .. nops([sequence])));
```

[image]

This also works fine as expected. If there is any drawbacks or exceptions happy to listen
Thank you